# The set of homomorphism on $C_\infty(X)$ for a locally compact $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, group-homomorphism, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, which is not compact. $C_b(X)$ is a Banach algebra of all bounded continuous functions with the sup norm.
Let $C_\infty(X)$ be the Banach algebra of continuous functions such that for every $f \in C_\infty(X)$, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact subset $K$ such that if $x \notin K, |f(x)|_\infty < \epsilon$.
Let $p \notin X$ and define $\tilde{X} = X \cup p$. Topology on $\tilde{X}$ is topology on $X$ plus all complements of compact subsets of $X$. Notice that $\tilde{X}$ is compact Hausdorff. Set $\mathcal{B} = C(\tilde{X})$. $\mathcal{B}$ can be identified with the closed subalgebra of $C_b(X)$ generated by all $f \in C_\infty(X)$ and the constant function 1.

Let $\mathcal{A} = C_\infty(X)$. It is Banach algebra without unit. I need to determine $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$, a set of homomorphisms into R that are not identically zero. Using the fact that any homomorphism on $C(\tilde{X})$ is of the form $\phi(f) = f(y)$ for some $y \in \tilde{X}$, I figured any homomorphism in $\widehat{C_\infty(X)}$ is also of the form $\phi(g) = g(x)$ for some $x \in X$. Is this correct?

Comment: Your homomorphisms are postulated to be continuous or something like that?  And $\alpha$ is a **homomorphism** means $\alpha(f+g) = \alpha(f)+\alpha(g)$ and $\alpha(fg) = \alpha(f)\alpha(g)$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar Nothing about continuity. Yes, homomorphism here is a linear multiplicative functional not identically equal to zero

Comment: @GEdgar they are automatically continuous, hence a subset of the dual

Comment: Have you thought it out yourself? $C_\infty(X)$ is a subalgebra of $C(\tilde X)$, so can you extend the homomorphism from that subalgebra to the full algebra? If so, you get $y \in \tilde X$, which is either in $X$ itself, or $y = p$. What happens when $y = p$? Otherwise the expression that holds on the full algebra will still be true for the its restriction to the subalgebra.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, when $y = p$, this homo is zero on $C_\infty(X)$. When we map functions from $C_(\tilde{X})$ to the algebra generated by $C_\infty(X),1$, we get $g(y) = \alpha 1 + \beta f(y)$, where $f \in C_\infty(X)$.  When $y = p$, $f(y) = 0$.

Comment: I asked you to consider how to **extend homorphisms** from $C_\infty(X)$, a **subalgebra** of $C(\tilde X)$, to **homomorphisms** on $C(\tilde X)$. THEN to consider, that since the extended homomorphism can be expressed as $\phi(f) = f(y)$ for some $y \in \tilde X$, what the case $y = p$ would imply about the original **homomorphism** on $C_\infty(X)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair got it, thanks for the approach!

Comment: @PaulSinclair Every element in $C(\tilde{X})$ which is not in the subalgebra $C_\infty(X)$, can be written as $g(y) = \alpha 1 + \beta f(y)$ with $\alpha \neq 0$ and some $f \in C_\infty(X)$. Fix $\bar{\phi} \in \widehat{C_\infty(X)}$. Extend it to $\phi \in \widehat {C(\tilde{X})}$ by $\phi(g) = \alpha \phi(1) + \beta \bar{\phi}(f) = \alpha + \beta \bar{\phi}(f)$. Note that $\phi(g) = g(y)$ for some $y \in \tilde{X}$. If $y=p$, $\alpha + \beta \bar{\phi}(f) = g(p) = \alpha + \beta f(p) = \alpha$, hence $\bar{\phi}(f) = 0$.

Comment: But can $\bar\phi(f) = 0$ for all $f\in C_\infty(X)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148891/discussion-between-anna-vakarova-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: Well, for every $f \in C_\infty(X)$ there exists $g = \alpha 1 + \beta f$, $\beta \neq 0$. And we can evaluate the constructed functional $\phi$ at $g$, which gives us $\bar{\phi} = 0$ for all $f$. I understand my logic is incorrect somewhere, but unfortunately I fail to see where

Comment: But as you said in your first comment, a homomorphism cannot be identically $0$. So this isn't possible. Which means that a certain assumption we made must be false...

Comment: Cannot it be that there is no multiplicative linear functional on $C_\infty(X)$ that is not identically zero that extends to a multiplicative linear functional on $C(\tilde{X})$ that is of the form $g(p)$? Cause if I start from the other direction, start with $\phi \in \widehat{C(\tilde{X})}$ such that $\phi = g(p)$, it is identically zero on the sublalgebra $C_\infty(X)$.